# How to initialize whole array with -1 without loop

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Hey i am trying to initialize all the elements of array with -1. But the catch is without using any loop.

So i searched net and someone told to use,

```
int *arr = new int[n]{-1};
```

But this only assigning first element to -1.

So,my question is how can i assign ,help me out.

Comment: `std::vector<int> arr(n, -1);`

Comment: @Chandan Nick You can not. Using standard algorithms in fact means using loops. You can do it using standard containers as for example std::vector.

Comment: Please try to avoid explicitly allocating dynamic memory with `new`. Use a container like `std::vector<int>(n)` (or `std::array<int, n>` if `n` is known at compile time), or perhaps allocate with `std::make_unique<int[]>(n)`.

Comment: Also, a pointer is not an array.  The example that someone gave you does not do what you asked for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have noticed later,,its better ,what i want to do ...Thanks for this 
std::vector<int> arr(n, -1);
This will solve my problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int *arr = new int[10];
    std::fill(arr, arr + 10, -1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or even better [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int *arr = new int[10];
    std::fill_n(arr, 10, -1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @melk it does but the question is unclear if the OP is not supposed to use the loop in his code or is not supposed to use the loop at all...

Comment: `std::fill_n` would be tiny bit more convenient.

Comment: @NutCracker
yeh ,i know without traversing we can't initialize it with -1,,
using for loop to initialize is long code,,,
Thanks ,got new thing fill_n ,, doesn't matter if it internally using loop,,

Answer (score 3):

> How to initialize whole array with -1 without loop

Like this:

```
int array[] = {
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
};
```

If the size is not known at compile time, then a loop must be used - whether the loop is achieved with a control structure, goto (don't use it for this), recursion or call to a function that does the loop. You can avoid writing the loop yourself by using `std::fill_n` or one of its related functions, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60993477/2079303).

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's impossible if you don't want to write -1 multiple times, but we can assign without loop(In fact, we cannot use a loop to initialize an array even with loop.)

## Warning: a snippet just for fun, don't take this seriously. Not for any practical use

Recursion can replace any loop. This is a code that really doesn't have any loop at all.

```cpp
void fun(int* p, std::size_t n, std::size_t cur = 1u)
{
    *p = -1;
    if(n != cur) fun(p+1, n, cur+1)
}
```

Comment: Note that you could split the array in half and call recursively twice.  That would limit stack depth to log2(N)

Comment: @stark I understand, somrthing like merge sort. However, as I've mentioned, this is just for fun and I simply want to tell the OP recursion can replace any loop. So this one looks clearer. :) Thanks for pointing out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance the size of the array, you can fill it when you declare it:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int a[10] ={-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        std::cout<< a[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In case you have to dinamically allocate memory, using `std::fill` (from @NutCracker answer) seems a good choice.

Comment: Are you really suggesting this?  Suppose I have n = 65,536.

Comment: Then your fingers will be tired, but at least you didn't use a loop.

Comment: @stark Well, you can use meta programming to generate the initalisers to save the fingers :)

Comment: @einpoklum, in that case I'd wrote a shell script which writes the cpp code containing such initialization... In general I'd use cycles, but since the request was to avoid them I wrote the solution that does not require any library.

Comment: @Eddymage: An array created with `new` will be initialized at runtime anyway.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, you're right. Actually there are several solutions which allow to avoid using specific libraries.